# LinkedIn Sign In API recently intermittently failing

Tags: linkedin-api, auth0

I'm having intermittent issues with signing in to LinkedIn with the LinkedIn Sign In API.

By intermittent I mean, I have two LinkedIn accounts, and as of this week one of them is unable to use the API to sign in to external services, such as the LinkedIn application I develop.

I'm authenticating via Auth0, whose engineers have confirmed there is an issue:

> Over the last few weeks, the current version of the LinkedIn API for
>   sign-in has been intermittently failing when fetching the user
>   profile, causing a small number of users to fail to log in. The cause
>   of this issue is currently unknown, and is coming from LinkedIn
>   directly.

https://community.auth0.com/t/linkedin-connection-deprecated/20484/18

The Auth0 response i'm getting is the following (I've replaced senstivie response values with 'XX'):

```
{"name":"a0.response.invalid","message":"unknown error","json":{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile (status: 500 data: {\n  \"errorCode\": 0,\n  \"message\": \"Internal API server error\",\n  \"requestId\": \"XX\",\n  \"status\": 500,\n  \"timestamp\": 1550474289966\n})","state":"XX"},"status":0}
```

**I know this API is being depreciated in March**, but it's imperative that this API continues to work until the decommission date. I'm wondering if anyone has found a work around or solution to this issue, as it's impacting my ability to run real-world trials of my application scheduled in this week.

I've contacted LinkedIn support who directed me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth0 recently released a change to LinkedIn social connection, allowing you to use the new LinkedIn API (Version 2). You can change this by going to Connections-->Social-->LinkedIn-->Strategy Version dropdown and select Version 2. This should fix most of the login issues with the old deprecated version of LinkedIn API. More information [post](https://community.auth0.com/t/important-changes-in-linkedin-connections/21378).

Comment: V1 is not yet depreciated, and should still work. V2 does not provide anywhere close to the same data, and does not provide position or organisation information, which I require until the final decommission day. Appreciate your help though.